# iOS 4.3 Beta for Apple TV

Tags: ios, appletv, subtitle

I'm wondering if anyone knows what features will be offered in iOS 4.3 for Apple TV?  I'm primarily trying to find out if the Netflix app will be updated to support subtitles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good breakdown of new features over on [iLounge](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/new-in-ios-4.3-the-full-breakdown-with-screenshots/)

In summary;

Apple TV

- AirPlay improvements (stream some web videos and your own videos)
- iOS Software Number matches other iOS devices
- New On-Screen Keyboard Design

There don't appear to be any changes to Netflix but there's always a chance it'll appear in the final release.  You might have to wait for iOS 5

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if anyone knows what features will be offered in iOS 4.3

While in beta, we, Apple Developers with access to the developer portal, are prohibited to say anything regarding the beta iOS.

[image]

Comment: Then how are other sites, such as iLounge, able to report it?

Comment: Apple says what I pasted as an image, everyone can do whatever they want, but, they been warn.